# How to pass username in the profile URL in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a project that was built with reactjs, and now I have a profile where it will display the user information, and each user has an id like this.

```
http://localhost:3000/Your-Personal-profile/14
```

and I want to pass the username in the profile URL as well like this.

```
http://localhost:3000/Your-Personal-profile/14/john
```

so I have built the router like this

```
<Route path="/Your-Personal-profile/fullName/:id" exact/>
```

finally, this is what I did in another component when someone clicks on a username it will redirect to the user profile.

```
     <Link to={`/profile/fullName/${comment.UserId}`} className="user_name_1">
        @{post.fullName}
     </Link>
```

so is there any suggestion?

Comment: why do you have `fullname` in your path `path="/Your-Personal-profile/fullName/:id"`, I think it should be `path="/Your-Personal-profile/:id/:fullName"` if you want to get `http://localhost:3000/Your-Personal-profile/14/john
` ?

Comment: Ah, yeah i tried this as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: The `Link` links to `/profile/fullName/:id`, the `Route` only handles `Your-Personal-profile/fullName/:id` and your examples are `/Your-Personal-profile/:id/:userName` - please correct these so they match up.

Comment: what do you mean by it didn't work ? Did you try with the link `<Link to={'/Your-Personal-profile/${comment.UserId}/${post.fullName}'}`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé
Hey it worked thanks a lot, I made a mistake. please post it as an answer so i can vote your answers as the correct answer.

Comment: I posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your route to :

```
<Route path="/Your-Personal-profile/:id/:fullName" exact/>
```

Update your link to :

```
<Link to={`/Your-Personal-profile/${comment.UserId}/${post.fullName}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generatePath` in `react-router` like below;

```
<Link to={generatePath("/Your-Personal-profile/:id/:fullName", {id:5, fullName:"randomname"})}
```

Comment: what does the random name do? thanks for answering!